# 404 Errors on Every Page (Including Homepage) After Migrating From IIS to Apache

Tags: 404-error, migration, apache, iis

I recently migrated a client site from an IIS environment to a LAMP stack. The back end of the site works fine. I can log in and make any changes I like. The front end, however only displays 404 errors, even on the homepage.

I tried resetting the Permalinks.

I'm not running any redirect or caching plugins.

My HTACCESS file is both standard and writeable:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks,

ty

Comment: Is it a WP 404 or an apache 404? Can you load static files? How about /index.php? Is mod_rewrite enabled? What does the error log contain?

Comment: It's a WP 404. I don't think I'd be able to log into the dashboard if it was an Apache error.